# How can one explain Moses' Mother as more than 120 years?

Tags: age

I came with the fact that Moses' Mother died with a superior age than him:

> 7 Moses was **a hundred and twenty years old** when he died, yet his
> eyes were not weak nor his strength gone. (NIV)

And knowing that she conceived Moses with 120 to 140 years, I would like to know how such thing is possible. As it states in the *Talmud*:

> "A daughter of Levi" - How can this be? She was one **hundred thirty
> years old** and he calls her "a daughter"?! As R. Hama b. Hanina said:
> "She was Jochebed; she was conceived on the way [to Egypt] and born
> between the walls, as it says (Num. 26:59): 'Who was born to Levi in
> Egypt' - born in Egypt but not conceived." (*Shemot Rabbah 1:20*)

Comment: Please cite some Bible evidence that Jochebed was this old.

Comment: This Q might be more suited to the Mi Yodeya site here. It does not seem to have anything to do with Christianity.

Comment: This site is about bible hermeneutics.

Comment: And you are asking about the Talmud.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking in reference to Genesis 6:3
“Then the Lord said, “My Spirit shall not strive with man forever, because he also is flesh; nevertheless his days shall be one hundred and twenty years.”‬‬

This was not a limit on the lifespan of one human going forward, this was the decreed time before God flooded the Earth in Noah’s day.

Noah lived 950 years, 350 after the flood (Genesis 9:28-29)
Genesis 10 gives the years lived by his descendants, almost all lived past 120 years.

Comment: Hi Adam, welcome to the site. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour), and thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

I can find no biblical information to substantiate the age at which Moses' mother died. However, the following information may shed some light on your question.

Moses’ mother, Jochebed, was a Hebrew woman living in slavery in Egypt before the exodus. She was the daughter of a Levite, and she married Amram, another Levite (Exodus 2:1). According to Exodus 6:20, Jochebed married her nephew; thus, she was Amram’s aunt as well as his wife.

We know that Moses was born several years after their marriage because she already had a daughter who was old enough at the time of Moses’ infancy to act as a lookout (Exodus 2:4). This was likely Moses’ sister, Miriam the prophetess, who is mentioned by name in Exodus 15:20. Along with Moses and Miriam, Jochebed had at least one other child, Moses’ brother Aaron (Exodus 6:20).

Note that Moses' mother was the daughter of a Levite and married Amram, another Levite.  She was a married woman, and a mother, when she gave birth of Moses while living in Egypt. But where does it say she outlived her son, Moses?

Without knowing when she died it is not possible to estimate her age at the time of her death.  I hope I have not misunderstood your question.